# Incorrect result when using dynamic column name set in Dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
ecl_calc_modelling11 <- tibble(
      PNPL_Z_UP_3 = c(0.000967956),
      PNPL_Z_UP_6 = c(0.00275992146415037),
      PNPL_Z_UP_9 = c(0.00368962639393721),
      PNPL_Z_UP_12 = c(0.003517554),
      A_EACO_DIS_M3 = c(48886.1160623658),
      A_EACO_DIS_M6 = c(47220.0969381751),
      A_EACO_DIS_M9 = 45610.8550739867,
      A_EACO_DIS_M12 = 44056.45552,
      P_LGCO = 0.86353

    )
```

I am trying to create new column ECL_12M_Z_UP using mutate like this:

```
nameVarPeriod1 = "UP"

ecl_calc_modelling2 =  ecl_calc_modelling11 %>% 
          mutate( !!paste0('ECL_12M_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_3') := !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_3')) * A_EACO_DIS_M3 * P_LGCO) %>%
          mutate( !!paste0('ECL_12M_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_6') := !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_6')) * A_EACO_DIS_M6 * P_LGCO) %>%
          mutate( !!paste0('ECL_12M_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_9') := !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_9')) * A_EACO_DIS_M9 * P_LGCO) %>%
          mutate( !!paste0('ECL_12M_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_12') := !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_12')) * A_EACO_DIS_M12 * P_LGCO) %>%
          mutate (ECL_12M_Z_UP = ECL_12M_Z_UP_3 + ECL_12M_Z_UP_6 + ECL_12M_Z_UP_9 +ECL_12M_Z_UP_12)
```

This produced a result of 432 for ecl_calc_modelling2$ECL_12M_Z_UP. (I have checked using Excel and this result is correct).

Now, I would like to using dynamic approach for setting ECL_12M_Z_UP. So I use this code:

```
ecl_calc_modelling21 =  ecl_calc_modelling11 %>% 
          mutate( !!paste0('ECL_12M_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1)) := !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_3')) * A_EACO_DIS_M3 * P_LGCO +
                    !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_6')) * A_EACO_DIS_M6 * P_LGCO +
                    !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_9')) * A_EACO_DIS_M9 * P_LGCO +
                    !!as.name(paste0('PNPL_Z_',quo_name(nameVarPeriod1),'_12')) * A_EACO_DIS_M12 * P_LGCO )
```

But this code gave me a result of 406 for ECL_12M_Z_UP which is incorrect result. I have checked the code and tried to google but don't understand why it did not produce the correct result.

So I very much appreciate if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: As aside, analyzing data using quosures is almost never the correct approach. Instead, you can pivot the data longer, moving the variables separated by `_` into their own columns.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking like something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ecl_calc_modelling11 <- tibble(
    PNPL_Z_UP_3 = c(0.000967956),
    PNPL_Z_UP_6 = c(0.00275992146415037),
    PNPL_Z_UP_9 = c(0.00368962639393721),
    PNPL_Z_UP_12 = c(0.003517554),
    A_EACO_DIS_M3 = c(48886.1160623658),
    A_EACO_DIS_M6 = c(47220.0969381751),
    A_EACO_DIS_M9 = 45610.8550739867,
    A_EACO_DIS_M12 = 44056.45552,
    P_LGCO = 0.86353
    
)

ecl_calc_modelling11 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    transmute(PNPL_Z_UP = sum(c_across(starts_with('PNPL'))),
              A_EACO_DIS = sum(c_across(contains('DIS'))),
              P_LGCO)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   PNPL_Z_UP A_EACO_DIS P_LGCO
#>       <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    0.0109    185774.  0.864
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>